# Proving $f$ is continuous

Tags: analysis

I am solving the following problem. I need to show that the following statements are equivalent:

a. $f$ is continuous at $x_0$

b. If $[{x_n}]_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is any sequence in X converging to $x_0$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0)$

My solution is as follows:
Assume f is continuous at $x_0$ then $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$. Then I want to say if this true for every point in the function, then it is also true for the sequence of points.

This is all I have and would appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: "Assume $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x) = f(x_0)$." What does this even mean? There is no $n$, yet you are taking a limit as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: I have made the proper correction

Comment: Are you sure this is the definition of continuity that (a) is referring to? (Not an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition or an "open ball" definition?)

Comment: That’s a good question. It could be either. I assumed that the question was referring to the definiton I provided.

Comment: What definition have you provided? There is not a clear one as of now. Also, what is the domain and co-domain of $f$ ?

Comment: Proving this statement is very standard, and indeed you can easily find proof in many textbooks or websites. For example, see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequential_Continuity_is_Equivalent_to_Continuity_in_Metric_Space

Comment: Sorry, I did not provide the intended definition. It is $lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that we are working with metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ and a function $f:X\to Y$. I will provide an outline for this proof and take the definition of point-wise continuity to be the following:

> If $f:X\to Y$ is a function and $x_0\in X$, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ provided that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$, where
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)\Longleftrightarrow\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in X:\big[d_X(x,x_0)<\delta\Longrightarrow d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))<\varepsilon\big]$$

I will also take the definition of sequential convergence to be the following:

> If $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $X$ and $x_0\in X$, then $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x_0$ provided that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$, where $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0\Longleftrightarrow \forall\varepsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\big[n\geq N\Longrightarrow d_X(x_n,x_0)<\varepsilon\big]$$

**Outline for $a.\Longrightarrow b.$**

Let $f:X\to Y$ be continuous at $x_0\in X$. Let $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$ which converges to $x_0$. We want to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0)$, so let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0\in X$, then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x\in X$, if $d_X(x,x_0)<\delta$, then $d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))<\varepsilon$. Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$, then there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq N$, then $d_X(x_n,x_0)<\delta$. The conclusion should be clear from this point (feel free to ask for clarity if needed).

**Outline for $b.\Longrightarrow a.$**

Here is an outline for the contrapositive, i.e., $\neg a.\Longrightarrow\neg b.$. Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is not continuous at $x_0\in X$. Then, by negating the definition of continuity, there exists an $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$, there exists an $x\in X$ with $d_X(x,x_0)<\delta$ but $d_Y(f(x),f(x_0))\geq \varepsilon_0$. Consider the sequence $\delta_n=\frac{1}{n}$. The sequence $\left(\delta_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defines a sequence $\left(x_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ because for each $\delta_n>0$, there exists an $x_n\in X$ with $d_X(x_n,x_0)<\delta_n$ but $d_Y(f(x_n),f(x_0))\geq \varepsilon_0$. Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$ and conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\neq f(x_0)$ by showing the negation of the definition I provided for sequential convergence.

Comment: @C squared can you please provide clarity for the conclusion to the outline for a $\to$ b.

Comment: @Fredsaffiyre well, you need to find a natural number $N'$ so that for all $n\geq N'$, we have $d_Y(f(x_n),f(x_0))<\varepsilon$. But for every $n\geq N$, we have $d_X(x_n,x_0)<\delta$ so using continuity we have $d_Y(f(x_n),f(x_0))<\varepsilon$. Choose $N'=N$.